# In NiFi, can I enter encrypted password in the custom.properties file and decrypt it in-memory in the corresponding processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

To make a flow and controller services environment agnostic(So that moving from dev-stage-prod would be easy), I am using variables/Expression language for passwords and usernames. And plan to read them the passwords/usernames from a custom.properties file or in process group variables. 
Not very comfortable in typing out the password directly in either. So would like to use some form of encryption and later decrypt it in the needed processors.(Can NIFI decrypt it in memory for all processors?)

Example : If  am using a JDBC connection pool and the password for connecting to the DB through controller service be “badPassword”.

In custom.properties file,

my.password.for.JDBC.connection.pool = badPassword

And in the controller service for Password  the value would be ${ my.password.for.JDBC.connection.pool }

The same example could be applied for different processors like FTP, SFTP or to invoke http processor where there is a Basic Authorization token.

Is there way to encrypt it and enter the encrypted password in the custom.properties file or in the process group variables and decrypt it in the corresponding processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open Jira for this feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2653), and with the upcoming [Apache NiFi Registry](https://nifi.apache.org/registry.html) effort, the flow versioning will allow for promotion of flows between dev/test/prod environments with referenced variable credentials. At this time, however, the variable registry values (your `custom.properties` values) cannot be encrypted.

Comment: Thank you Andy..  Is there a work around for this? Any best solution to handle this now?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a quick fix answer for this -- implementing the behavior for custom properties shouldn't be too difficult because I've already written all the crypto code for the "native" properties, I just need to wire it into the VR loading because that was added later. The issue is that I have other priorities for the foreseeable future. The code is open source though, and if you need the feature immediately, I encourage you to take a look about copying the logic directly in your own fork. Help is available on the mailing lists or here.

Comment: Sure. Thank you Andy.